# How do I match a string that begins with backward slash followed by a question mark like /?<any_string>=<any_value> with regex

Tags: regex, string

How would I match a regex that matches a string that begins exactly with `/?` which is then followed by `{{key=value}}`. For example, I would expect the regex to match with `/?x=123` or `/?example=ex`

Comment: Something like `/\?\w+=\w+` and `?` is a regex metacharacter that needs to be escaped when matching a literal `?`

Comment: Not sure why it is not working for JS: https://jsfiddle.net/f7krmpyv/

Comment: Its not really a regex until its compiled as one. This way uses the `//` delimiters [/\/\?\w+=\w+/](https://jsfiddle.net/y4ju53dp/)

Comment: Still adding the delimiters is still not working for JS: https://jsfiddle.net/v5b476mL/2/

Comment: Single quoted strings in JS follow the same rules as double quoted ones. https://jsfiddle.net/m9j84db6/